# How to make my grid group columns read-only in Windows Form DevExpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to make read-only group columns.

```
baseGrid.gvForm.Columns["Column"].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = false;
baseGrid.gvForm.Columns["Column"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
```

I think it can be like that grouped version. Could you help me ? Really I couldn't find.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like all the columns in the your grid to be read-only?

Comment: No no , Let explain you . I gave a list to DataGrid Data Source. A list has list properties.

Comment: It's name is called also master detail grid.

Comment: your current code is how i do it, so what is not working for you ? For readonly you do have to set true to the readonly property and false to the allowedit property